# Additional drivers not showing current Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xserver

I am currently using Nvidia proprietary driver 340.46, which shows corrrectly in Nvidia XServer settings, but not in the Additional Drivers application.  Does anyone know why this might be?

To clarify:

XServer shows 340.46

nvidia-smi shows 340.46

**however:**   Additional Drivers shows 331.38

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is this on a new install? If so: `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: No, not a new install.  As near as I can tell, the driver in use is 340.46, but I can't explain the Additional Drivers issue.